# Azure multiple tcp ports

Tags: azure, tcp, containers, port

I'm working with linux containers on Microsoft Azure.

I still have a problem. I would like to expose multiple ports for tcp communication. My dockerFile contains the lines below :

```
EXPOSE 10038
EXPOSE 10004
EXPOSE 10003
```

Also, when I created my container I opened ports like :

```
az container create --resource-group ....... --ports 10038, 10003, 10004
```

I can reach my container through telnet via 10038 (FQDN). I cannot access it from 10003 or 10004.
I can see that on Azure portal container properties, all these ports are "open".

Have you ever met something like that. Does someone has a solution please ?

EDIT: I re-built my container exposing only 10038. I can not reach my container.

Comment: What about now? Do you solve the problem or change the requirement? Can you provide more details such as the Dockerfile and steps to deploy to ACI?

Answer (score 0):

can you try executing the command and specify all ports without a comma.

```
az container create --resource-group ....... --ports 10038 10003 10004
```

See reference here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I built a container exposing only 10038. I used EXPOSE 10038 and --port 10038 when I created my container, not reachable.

Comment: If you also requested a public-ip adress, than it feels like your service within the container did not start correct or is not listening on 10038. [TroubleshootMismatchedPorts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-group-ip-address-may-not-be-accessible-due-to-mismatched-ports)